# Unable to Deserialize String with JSON Contents to C# Object

Tags: c#, json.net, dotnet-httpclient

I have an HttpClient that makes a call to a REST API.

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("Payments/CreditCard", content);
var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

When I read the content of the response as a string, I get the following result:

```
"\"{\\\"ssl_card_number\\\":\\\"41**********9994\\\",\\\"ssl_exp_date\\\":\\\"1219\\\",\\\"ssl_amount\\\":\\\"50.00\\\",\\\"ssl_salestax\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"ssl_invoice_number\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"ssl_departure_date\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"ssl_completion_date\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"Test\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"TestField\\\":\\\"TestValue\\\",\\\"ssl_result\\\":\\\"0\\\",\\\"ssl_result_message\\\":\\\"APPROVAL\\\",\\\"ssl_approval_code\\\":\\\"578380\\\",\\\"ssl_cvv2_response\\\":\\\"U\\\",\\\"ssl_avs_response\\\":\\\"G\\\",\\\"ssl_account_balance\\\":\\\"0.00\\\",\\\"ssl_txn_time\\\":\\\"04/09/2018 09:41:01 AM\\\",\\\"ssl_card_type\\\":\\\"CREDITCARD\\\"}\""
```

When I debug and inspect the value of the `contents` variable, it contains the following:

[image]

When I try to deserialize the string into a C# object using JSON.Net, I receive an exception, because the contents variable can't be converted to my C# object.
However, if I take the string from the Text Visualizer, I'm able to successfully convert it to my C# object.

Here's the class I'm trying to deserialize the string contents into:

```
public class PaymentResponse
{
     public string ssl_account_balance { get; set; }
     public string ssl_amount { get; set; }
     public string ssl_approval_code { get; set; }
     public string ssl_avs_response { get; set; }
     public string ssl_card_number { get; set; }
     public string ssl_card_type { get; set; }
     public string ssl_completion_date { get; set; }
     public string ssl_cvv2_response { get; set; }
     public string ssl_departure_date { get; set; }
     public string ssl_exp_date { get; set; }
     public string ssl_invoice_number { get; set; }
     public string ssl_result { get; set; }
     public string ssl_result_message { get; set; }
     public string ssl_salestax { get; set; }
     public string ssl_txn_id { get; set; }
     public string ssl_txn_time { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the code I use for deserializing:

```
paymentResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaymentResponse>(contents);
```

How can I get my contents variable to have the same value that appears in the Text Visualizer?

Comment: If you have control of the source of the data check to make sure you are not double serializing the data

Comment: Post your class and deserialization code.

Comment: @AndersonPimentel, I've added the class and code used for deserialization.

Comment: @Nkosi, by source do you mean the response from the API? If so, I don't have control over it.

Comment: well this may just be a guess, but how about deserializing it twice. first to string and then to desired type

Comment: @Nkosi, submit that as the answer, and I'll accept it. I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data shown appears to be serialized twice.

In that case it would need to be deserialized twice.

First to `string`,

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(contents);
```

and then to the desired type

```
var paymentResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaymentResponse>(json);
```

Answer (score 4):

@Nkosi was right: first deserialize it to `string` and then to `PaymentResponse`:

```
var contents = "\"{\\\"ssl_card_number\\\":\\\"41**********9994\\\",\\\"ssl_exp_date\\\":\\\"1219\\\",\\\"ssl_amount\\\":\\\"50.00\\\",\\\"ssl_salestax\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"ssl_invoice_number\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"ssl_departure_date\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"ssl_completion_date\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"Test\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"TestField\\\":\\\"TestValue\\\",\\\"ssl_result\\\":\\\"0\\\",\\\"ssl_result_message\\\":\\\"APPROVAL\\\",\\\"ssl_approval_code\\\":\\\"578380\\\",\\\"ssl_cvv2_response\\\":\\\"U\\\",\\\"ssl_avs_response\\\":\\\"G\\\",\\\"ssl_account_balance\\\":\\\"0.00\\\",\\\"ssl_txn_time\\\":\\\"04/09/2018 09:41:01 AM\\\",\\\"ssl_card_type\\\":\\\"CREDITCARD\\\"}\"";
var contentAsString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(contents);
var paymentResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaymentResponse>(contentAsString);
Console.WriteLine(paymentResponse.ssl_card_number);
```

Check the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A5m1pT).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. Actually we need to take care about the Encoding while deserializing to object. Since the content string of the object would sometimes have other than ASCII charset. It worked fine for me.

```
var resultBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
var actualEncodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBytes);
var actualObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(actualEncodedString);
```